# How to extract a piece of text within double quotes from a line

Tags: shell

He is a nice guy. "Rob" doesn't like it though.

How to extract ***Rob*** from this line using shell script?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way of doing it, the first that came to my mind:

```
echo "He is a nice guy. \"Rob\" doesn't like it though" | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Of course it could have been done with sed or awk.

Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "He is a nice guy. \"Rob\" doesn't like it though." | gawk -F'"' '{print $2}'
Rob
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the shell

```
$ string="He is a nice guy. \"Rob\" doesn't like it though."
$ string=${string#*\"}
$ echo ${string%%\"*}
Rob
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, try this

```
echo "ROB" | tr ""''
```

The first two "" are double quotes and the last two are single quotes