# Bash - Extract content within quotes from a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string that looks like:

```
result='SNMP OK - "-63.1" |'   # output should be -63.1
result='SNMP OK - "63.1"  |'   # output should be 63.1
```

I need the to output everything between the quotes -- which should always be numeric.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: SNMP OK - "-63.1" |

Comment: This looks awfully like http://superuser.com/questions/515421/using-sed-get-substring-between-two-double-quotes

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796332/how-to-extract-a-piece-of-text-within-double-quotes-from-a-line

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636323/extracting-a-string-between-two-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var='SNMP OK - "-63.1"'; 
newvar=$(echo "$var" | sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/')
echo "$newvar"

-63.1
```